# CSS: Heading margin in div

Tags: html, css

HTML/CSS newbie here. I want to create a div (in blue), with an h1 at the top (in red). The h1 should have a margin of 30px all around. Below h1 is another div (in green). The following code "should" work, but the result I get is that h1 only has a 30px margin on the left, bottom and right. The top has no margin. Why is this?

To see what I mean, you can try this code out at http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

div#frame1
{
padding:0px;
margin:50px auto;
width:500px;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}

h1
{
padding:0px;
margin:30px;
text-align:center;
background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

div#frame2
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="frame1">

<h1>Hello world</h1>

<div id="frame2">
Hello again
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). To correct that behavior, add `overflow:auto` (or a border) to your frame1 div:

```
div#frame1 {
    padding:0px;
    margin:50px auto;
    width:500px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cVQsm/)**

Comment: Thanks. Would a more elegant method be to add padding to div1, rather than a margin to h1? Is padding generally preferable to margins, in cases when the visual outcome is identical?

Comment: Well you shouldn't have to add either padding nor a margin since the overflow rule fixes the issue. But the padding vs margin question really is layout dependent anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your should add `overflow: auto;` to your `div#frame1` styling and it should fix it. Collapsing margins will occur otherwise.

CSS should read:

```
#frame1 {
   padding:0px;
   margin:50px auto;
   width:500px;
   background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Side note (I don't think this would affect anything, but it might): calling `div#frame1` in your CSS is redundant.  Just calling `#frame1` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Your heading does have a 30px margin. The issue is that *margins do not contain the background color*. You need to use `padding` if you want the background color to extend, not margin.

```
padding:30px;
```